# restore windows command prompt tools after git bash replace them with unix tools

Tags: windows, git, unix, command-prompt, git-bash

I installed Git bash and chose the option "Use Git and optional Unix tools from the windows Command Prompt". I know there is a big red warning but I thought it was "cool" for unix tools a far better than the Windows ones. I didnt really think about the implications..

So I wanted to revert the change by restoring the windows tools (I really need that) but after uninstalling git, making sure there is no other find.exe rather than the one sign by Micorsoft, restart the computer a few times, check in the environment variables and in the registry.. the command prompt still uses the Unix tools (I can see for example by different behavior of the find command).

How does the command prompt load the list of available commands and reference them?

Thanks

Comment: What is the contents of your `PATH`?  Do you see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git...`?

Comment: the problem was the PATH variable but not because of Git. I've also installed Rtools and they inserted c:\Program files\Rtools\bin in the path and there is find.exe too. I found it helpful using the "where find" command in the the command windows which tells you from where it launches the tool. That's how I found out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command prompt loads the tools using the PATH environment variable.

Using "where" + the name of a tool ("where find" for example), you can see the list of paths from where it looks for the command.

So removing the path you dont need from the variable solve the problem.